# Why the output of *(pa-1) is the last element of `a`?

Tags: c++

What I got from the output of below code is `*(pa-1)=5`: why so?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *pa=(int *)(&a+1);

    cout<<"*(pa-1)="<<*(pa-1)<<endl;

}
```

Comment: pretty sure its undefined behavior since you're casting a pointer to an int array to a pointer to an int

Comment: @DanF: As long as `T` is standard-layout, `(T*)[N]` is convertible to `T*` and gives the address of the first element.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`&a` is the address of the array, and it has type "pointer-to-`int[5]`". Thus `&a + 1` advances by an entire array-of-five and points just past the array.

`pa` is a type-punned pointer* that now treats the same address as an address inside an array of *integers* (not arrays!). It is thus identical to the one-past-the-end pointer `a + 5`. Decrementing by one gives a pointer to the last element in the array, which is `5`.

<sub>*) This sort of type punning is acceptable and does what you expect as long as the underlying type of the array is *standard-layout*, which `int` is.</sub>

Comment: Array's are special: `a` is it's own address, and `&a` == `a` - though with different types.  Great write up.

Comment: @RichardSitze: Yeah, lots of things have the same address. It's the *pair* of type and value that designate unique objects. You can easily make a long list of descending subobjects which all have the same address, too.

Comment: @RichardSitze, the C standard does not forbid one from obtaining a pointer to array with the `address-of` operator and it results into a pointer of type `type (*)[N]`. The answer is correct.

Comment: @HristoIliev: I don't think Richard was complaining. He was just pointing out that arrays are unique in the sense that the variable name itself can act as an address of the same value as the object's address, albeit differently typed. He should probably have said `(void*)(a) == (void*)(&a)`, though :-)

Comment: @RichardSitze Not according to anything I've seen (including the standard).  The type of `a` is `int[5]`.  The type of `&a` is `int (*)[5]`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, it looked like a complaint before he edited his comment.

Comment: @KerrekSB Anything of type `T[]` will convert implicitly to `T*` in certain contexts.  That's irrelevant here, however, since operand of an address-of operator isn't one of those contexts.

Comment: @RichardSitze: Where does the C standard specify that `&a == a` or that converting a pointer to an array of int to a pointer to int yields the address of the first element? (The fact that it commonly works in most C implementations does not mean it is reliable behavior or conforming C code.)

Comment: Thanks Kerrek & all for the correction: yes `(void*)(a) == (void*)(&a)` is what I should have said.

Comment: @RichardSitze: Actually, you should convert to `char *`, not `void *`. The 1999 C standard says, in 6.3.2.3 7, that converting a pointer to a character type yields the lowest addressed byte of the object. So `(char *) a` and `(char *) &a` must yield the same address. No such guarantee is started for conversion to `void *`, so converting to `void *` may give different values or, when compared, undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

What else would you expect?  `&a` has type `int (*)[5]`, so `&a + 1` points
to the next `int[5]` after `a`; it is the classical "end" iterator for
iterating over `int[5]` elements.  You then `reinterpret_cast` it to an
`int*`, and access that.  Formally, I think your code has undefined
behavior, since about the only thing you can legally do with the results
of a `reinterpret_cast` are to cast it back to the original type.
(There are exceptions where pointers to character types are involved.)
In practice, various requirements spread out throughout the standard
mean that you will get the address of the last `int` in `a`.

Comment: `(int*)[5]` isn't a legal type expression.  The type of `&a` is `int (*)[5]`, a pointer to an array of 5 `int`.

Comment: The type is `int (*)[5]`. See §6.7.6 of the C99 standard for the syntax.

Comment: @KerrekSB Fixed it:-).  (I think I must have accidentally mis-edited something before posting.  Maybe along the lines of `a` has type `int [5]`, so `&a` has type `int (*)[5]`.)

Comment: Just to be sure, I believe this is *not* UB, since it is permissible to treat a pointer to an object as the pointer to the first member or element when the type is standard-layout.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's possible that this has changed in C++11.  Earlier, at least, it was undefined behavior: the C standard was carefully crafted to allow "fat" pointers, which included things like bounds information (and presumably some type information as well) so that a fully checking implementation was possible.  Earlier C++ also allowed this, and at least one compiler in the past implemented it.